# How do I write a cursor to return only one column that contains digit values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

For example I had a table named car with two column(col1,col2)

For now I would like insert some values inside the column like:

('Super car','Yellow car')

('BMW5','XL')

('Benz','AGM')

so I would like write a cursor to return ('BMW5','XL') in one single column, how do I do that?(I'm using sql developer)

I would appreciate any suggestion! Thank you!

```
declare
cursor mycursor is select concat(col1,col2) from car where REGEXP_LIKE(left, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
begin
for counter in mycursor
loop
dbms_output.put_line(counter.concat);
endloop;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat()` function in your query inside the `cursor` i.e.

`CONCAT` returns `Col1` concatenated with `Col2`

```
select concat(col1,col2)
from car where <<conditions if any>>
```

You can write above query in `Cursor` like

```
DECLARE
CURSOR car_cursor IS select concat(col1,col2)
                     from car WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '[[:digit:]]');
cv_col1_col2 VARCHAR2 ;

BEGIN

OPEN car_cursor;
LOOP
FETCH car_cursor INTO cv_col1_col2;
Dbms_output.put_line('Concated Name' || cv_col1_col2)
END LOOP
CLOSE car_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the correct format that select rows only contains digit number

Comment: I think you wanted to search the `columname` which contains number only. In that case use  `Oracle` `REGEXP_LIKE` condition i.e. `SELECT col1 
FROM car 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^[[:digit:]]+$');`

Comment: ie. BMW5 is in col1 and XL is in col2, now I would like display 'BMW5 and XL' in one single column instead of display them in two columns

Comment: By using cursor

Comment: Yes that is but how to display them in one single column

Comment: @TIGUZI, the same is mentioned in my answer, write a cursor and use above query inside the cursor it will provide expected result

Comment: I tried this code(post updated), I don't know where am I wrong....

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question (though, more through by description than the title as they aren't related much).

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table car (col1 varchar2(10), col2 varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into car
  2    select 'Super car', 'Yellow car' from dual union all
  3    select 'BMW5', 'XL'              from dual union all
  4    select 'Benz', 'AGM'             from dual;

3 rows created.
```

PL/SQL code that uses a cursor FOR loop, returning concatenated `col1` and `col2` values for rows in which either of those columns contains a digit:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select col1 ||' '|| col2 result
  3                  from car
  4                  where regexp_like(col1 || col2, '\d')  -- any column contains
  5                 )                                       -- a digit
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.result);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
BMW5 XL

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```